# Signing a dll multiple times different certificates?

Tags: c#, code-signing-certificate

I have received a third party dll. running sn.exe - T name.dll I get the public token Key so this is telling me that it is signed.

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is xXXXxxxXXXX

Question 1.
When I sign my own dll and right click on select properties I see Digital Signatures. On this dll I don't see this tab.why? if it is signed i should see it.

Question 2.
I have my own certificate and I want to sign this dll using my own certificate is it possible? What happens to the previous signing. Can you sign a dll with multiple keys(  I guess not just want to confirm).

Question 3.
For whatever reason I can sign this dll even though it has been signed before?? When I sign it using my own certificate i see it Digital signature tab when I click on properties.

not sure what is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

There are two sets of signatures in play here, the "[Strong Name signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx)" and the "[Authenticode signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(v=vs.85).aspx)".

The Strong Name signature is a .NET specific feature used to prove that "The assembly I compiled aginst and the assembly I am using at runtime was created by the same person, has the same version number, and was not modified by a 3rd party". This is the signature you saw via `sn.exe`, a .NET app can only have one strong name signature

The Authenticode signature is a feature of any `.cab`, `.cat`, `.ctl`, `.dll`, `.exe`, or `.ocx` file, this is used to prove "This file came from this specific source and was not modified". This is the signature you see on the "Digital Signatures" tab, a executeable can have more than one Authenticode signature but it is not common.

.NET does not have any "automatic" reading of Authenticode, it only checks the strong name of the file and if that passes or fails it stops the signature checks there.

To answer your questions specifically:

1. See the above description, strong name signings do not show up on the Digital Signatures tab. If a file has no Authenticode signatures Windows will not show the Digital Signatures tab.
2. If you strong name sign it you overwrite the old one, this will break your program if you do this after you compile your assembly and your assembly is set up to check strong name signatures because it will be expecting the old signature. This might also break other software that uses the same 3rd party DLL as they will be expecting the original signature from the vendor.

   If you Authenticode sign it you append your signature to the list of Authenticode signatures on the file. This will not affect the runtime of .NET unless you have custom code checking for Authenticode signatures.
3. You are signing it via Authenticode so you are just appending your signature to the Authenticode list, you are not modifying the strong name signature.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I got it now. i am using signtool.exe" sign  to sign dll I believe this is only for Authenticode part. If I need strong name on this then I would use sn.exe.

Comment: Then please up vote and accept the answer if I answered your question.

Comment: Side note: in addition to generally wrecking havoc with dependencies,  re-compiling third party DLL to sign with new strong name may be against license agreement - make sure to check if it is ok to do in each particular case.

Comment: @user1088352 To address your question in the comments (Did not see it at first), yes `signtool.exe` is exclusively for Authenticode signing.